# Ontology similar to PeriodicTable for integrated search

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, sparql, owl, jena

I am developing an application that queries [PeriodicTable ontology](http://www.daml.org/2003/01/periodictable/PeriodicTable.owl). Is there some other ontology similar to this that can be queried with it? Basically, I am in search of ontology that can I query with the PeriodicTable ontology and extract meaningful data. PeriodicTable ontology contains all the elements of periodic table with their name, symbol, and atomic number.

Comment: Please, provide a link to the PeriodicTable ontology. Also, define what you mean by "meaningful".

Comment: http://www.daml.org/2003/01/periodictable/PeriodicTable.owl and by meaningful,i meant that data common from both the oontologies

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can query dbpedia's SPARQL endpoint http://dbpedia.org/sparql

For example ...

```
select * where { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hydrogen> ?p ?o}
```

Also from OpenCYC, see:

http://sw.opencyc.org/2008/06/10/concept/en/Hydrogen

And from http://sameAs.org you can also get equivalent Linked Data URIs for a given element. See ...

http://sameas.org/html?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FHydrogen&x=0&y=0

For an integrated search http://sameas.org is a very valuable resource. You can use its restful API for finding URIs that refer to the same Periodic element, then HTTP resolve each of those to get the RDF data.

**how to get all the periodic element with curl**

The following command will download the RDF document for Hydrogen from dbpedia:

```
curl -L -H "Accept: application/rdf+xml" http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hydrogen
```

If you have the names of all the elements you can try to resolve all of them and put then in a local store.

Comment: Is  there some local version available for the elements as I am having some Problem sending query to enpoint.I don't wikipedia locally as its too big and it will take more time to query it

Comment: For just the elements no, I don't think so. What you could do is resolve them all and put them in a local store. See curl command in the answer.